# Indexing table in [R]

Tags: r, indexing

I have a vector:

```
a = c(1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, NA)
```

I want to generate something like:

```
[["1"]]
1, 6, 7
[["2"]]
3, 4
[["3"]]
2
[["5"]]
5
```

Mapping from value to index. Any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a `split` operation on the indexes of `a`:

```
split(seq_along(a), a)

#$`1`
#[1] 1 6 7
#
#$`2`
#[1] 3 4
#
#$`3`
#[1] 2
# 
#$`4`
#[1] 5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setNames(lapply(unique(a), function(x) which(x == a)), unique(a))

# $`1`
# [1] 1 6 7
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 2
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 3 4
# 
# $`4`
# [1] 5
# 
# $<NA>
# integer(0)
```

This is slightly shorter using tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
map(unique(a) %>% setNames(.,.), ~which(.x == a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option with `unstack`

```
unstack(list(i = seq_along(a), a), i ~ a)
#$`1`
#[1] 1 6 7

#$`2`
#[1] 3 4

#$`3`
#[1] 2

#$`4`
#[1] 5
```